# how to pass multiple data values in option list?

Tags: php, jquery

Hey how do I pass multiple data value to option list and access them in jquery

```
$output .='<option value="'.$row['rate_id'].'" currency='.get_room_currency($row['currency']).'>'.stripcslashes($row['rate_name']).' - '.$row['price'].''.get_room_currency($row['currency']).'</option>';
```

I can get access to 'rate_id' but the unable to get the 'currency' value..

Actually what I want to do .. on change the value of option list is to get the rate_id and currency and assign them to the separate input field

The below is how I access values but nothing is get alerted..

```
    $('#selectpicker2').on('hidden.bs.select', function (e) {
      var data = this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text.split("-");
      $('.roomPrice_').val(data['1']);
      $('.mycurrency').val(data['2']);
      alert('Price = ' + data['1']+ ' And currency = ' + data['2']);
});
```

Comment: There is not a currency attribute for option tag. Use data-* attributes for this: e.g. data-currency. Then it will be available with jquery .data() tool

Comment: `$(selector).find('option:selected').attr('currency');`, However use `data-currency` attribute then you can use `$(selector).find('option:selected').data('currency');`

Comment: Satap ..I access the data values as follows  $('#selectpicker2').on('hidden.bs.select', function (e) {
    var data = this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text.split("-");
    $('.roomPrice_').val(data['1']);
    $('.mycurrency').val(data['2']);
    alert('Price = ' + data['1']+ ' And currency = ' + data['2']);
 });